# How to check the emit value when it's called by mock function

Tags: angular8, angular-test, angular-testing-library

I am using https://testing-library.com/ for test my angular app.

Here is my component function:

```
onCreateFormSubmit() {

    if (this.createForm.valid && this.crud.isCreate) {
        this.ssCreated.emit(created); //emits the data, needs to test
    }

}
```

test spec:

```
test('Testing add Subsystem operation', async () => {

    const data = {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'subsystem2',
        IsDeletePossible: true,
        CreatedBy: '',
        CreatedDate: new Date(),
        UpdatedBy: '',
        UpdatedDate: new Date(),
        UpdatedByName: 'test value',
        CreatedByName: ''
    } as ModelSubSystem;

    const ssCreatedEmit = jest.fn();

    const component = await render(SubSystemComponent, {
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            StoreModule.forRoot({}, { runtimeChecks: { strictStateImmutability: true, strictActionImmutability: true } }),
            StoreModule.forFeature('pfservice', reducer),
            EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
            EffectsModule.forFeature([EffectsSubSystem])
        ],
        componentProperties: {
            onCreateFormSubmit: jest.fn(),
            ssCreated: {
                emit: ssCreatedEmit
            } as any,
        }

    });

    const componentInstance = component.fixture.componentInstance;


    /*
     *   Testing the form by DOM.
     */

    const createButton = component.getByTestId('btn-addRow');
    component.click(createButton);
    component.fixture.detectChanges();
    // status changes because of click on button
    expect(componentInstance.crud.isCreate).toBeTruthy();

    component.fixture.detectChanges();
    // onclick submit should not called, becasue of empty input

    component.input(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-0'), {
        target: {
            value: data.Id
        }
    });

    component.input(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-1'), {
        target: {
            value: data.Name
        }
    });


    component.blur(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-1'));

    component.input(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-2'), {
        target: {
            value: data.UpdatedByName
        }
    });

    const submit = component.getAllByTestId('form-create-btn')[0];

    component.click(submit);

    component.fixture.detectChanges();
    const name = componentInstance.createForm.controls['Name'];
    const updatedByName = componentInstance.createForm.controls['UpdatedByName'];
    expect(name.value).toEqual(data.Name);
    expect(name.errors).toBeFalsy();
    expect(updatedByName.value).toEqual(data.UpdatedByName);
    expect(componentInstance.onCreateFormSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); //works.

    expect(componentInstance.ssCreated).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data); // not works throw error

});
```

getting error as :

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

how to check my emit data with the data i sets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're `spy`ing on the `emit` function.
Thus, you should do: `expect(componentInstance.ssCreated.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data)`

For an example see https://github.com/testing-library/angular-testing-library/blob/master/src/app/examples/02-input-output.spec.ts